# Opencv extract text from image

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I need to remove everything but the black text from an image.

I tried using threshold, adaptiveThreshold but nothing seems to work properly.

I also tried iterate throught all the pixels and change anything that wasn't black, or almost black, to absolute white, and the keep the rest absolute black. But it took too long and the result wasn't good too.

The image I'm trying to extract the texts is that.
[image from crv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUMbz.jpg)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: you should cover personal informations..

Comment: If you want to extract the text, you should look at OCR algorithms.

Comment: The informations were changed. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Actually I wan to to filter the image to do OCR on it.
I already tried OCR algorithms with the original image, and treated image too. The result was not goog, that's why I need to filter only the text from the image.